# SpringBoot Returning a String rather than a rendered html page

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have created a spring boot application by using a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse with the following file setup:
[image]

My spring boot configuration was not configured using maven and thus without a pom.xml file(I instead imported all dependencies needed). My App file contains the running of spring boot:

```
package Main;


import java.util.Collections;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
    app.setDefaultProperties(Collections
            .singletonMap("server.port", "9004"));
    app.run(args);
}

}
```

I am also attempting to render a html page called test.html:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Number: <span th:text="${number}"></span></p>
    <p>Name: <span th:text="${firstName}"></span></p>
</body>
```

Render it via springboot as so:

```
package Main;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController 
{
@GetMapping("testing")
@ResponseBody
public String testPage(Model model) 
{
    String name = "John";
    model.addAttribute("number", 42);
    model.addAttribute("firstName", name);
    return "test";



}
}
```

The issue I am having is that it is returning the string test, rather then test.html. I have attempted using @RestController instead(removing @ResponseBody) with no luck. I am pretty sure it has to do with the URL to test.html but I am not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@ResponseBody` and Spring will attempt to look up the view to return.

The reason why removing `@ResponseBody` but adding `@RestController` failed is the fact that `@RestController` is a meta-annotation combining `@ResponseBody` and `@Controller` i.e. nothing changed by doing that.

You can see on the [Controller](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) and [ResponseBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ResponseBody.html) documentation that the response body effectively means that the return value will be transformed to body of the http response rather than looking up a classical view for the controller.

Here's a working example of your code,

https://github.com/DarrenForsythe/so-67693611

I've additionally added a test that can verify the behavior without running the entire application,

```
package com.darrenforsythe.controllerview.so67693611;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;

import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.get;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.model;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.view;

@WebMvcTest
class MainControllerTests {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    MainControllerTests(MockMvc mockMvc) {
        this.mockMvc = mockMvc;
    }

    @Test
    void testViewShouldBeReturned() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/testing"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("test"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("firstName", "John"))
                .andExpect(model().attribute("number", 42));

    }
}
```

If you clone the repository and run the `build-and-run.sh` it should create the Spring Boot Jar, run it, and open the URL `http://localhost:9004/testing`.

My guess that your IDE has no synced the resources, a clean build might resolve it.

Comment: If I remove "@ResponseBody" in this case I get a 404 error that it cant find /testing. This is solved using "@RestController" instead but it also causes same issue of returning the string "test" rather than test.html

Comment: Yes, it cannot find the `test` view in that case. As mentioned `ResponseBody` is used to transform the return value to the body of a response e.g. when you want to return a JSON Object. I would ensure that your resource folders are being packaged when built

Comment: Yes but this is my whole issue. I am trying to figure out why spring boot cannot find the test.html. I have even attempted other methods such as return new ModelAndView("test.html"); and this is unsuccessful as well.

Comment: @JmanxC I've updated my answer with a working example and repository.